# deleting item in sharedPreferences from recyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

i tried to delete an item in sharedPreferences, in recyclerView adapter. but that item doesn't disappear till I go back from the activity and come back. I need it to disappear soon after being deleted.

**Method**

```
public boolean RemoveFromWantToRead(AllBooksActivityModel book) {
        ArrayList<AllBooksActivityModel>books = getWantToReadBooks();
        if (null != books){
            for (AllBooksActivityModel b: books){
                if (b.getBookID() == book.getBookID()){
                    if (books.remove(b)){
                        //We create a 'if' loop here is if only the thing happened, the loop actions.
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.remove(WANT_TO_READ_BOOKS);
                        editor.putString(WANT_TO_READ_BOOKS,gson.toJson(books));
                        editor.commit();
                        return true;
                    }

                }            }
        }return false;
    }
```

This is how I tried to delete an item.

```
 holder.BtnDltTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete this massage");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            String EleName = allBooksActivityModels.get(position).getBookName();
                            if( Ulitls.getInstance(context).RemoveFromCurrenlyReading(allBooksActivityModels.get(position))){
                                Toast.makeText(context, EleName + " Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Something Wrong Happens, Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: use this code `books.remove(position);` where you want to remove from recyclerView. Here `books` is your ArrayList of books.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219124/how-to-remove-the-exact-item-from-recyclerview-in-android-studio. Can you check it out @Shanuka_N?