# how to remove the exact item from recyclerview in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to delete the item from the recyclerview, but after deleting it always removes the last position, I can't understand why it is not removing the exact position which I have deleted

please if anyone could help me out of this problem

here is my code

```
  holder.items_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            item_card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            item_delete_layer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final String path = imageList.get(position).getPath();
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("path", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("filePath", path);
                editor.apply();
        }
    });


item_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            item_card.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            item_delete_layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("path", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String path = sharedPreferences.getString("filePath","");
            File fdelete = new File(path);
            if (fdelete.delete()){
                imageList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(context, "File deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Can't delete file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


 item_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            item_card.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            item_delete_layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("path",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();


        }
    });
```

Comment: You just need to remove item from list which is passed in the recyclerview and then refresh the recyclerview with notify method.

Comment: use notifyItemRemoved instead of notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif it shows the same problem

Comment: @AishaKumari please share your adapter code so that we can further understand the problem.

Comment: You don't show where ```position``` variable comes from, use ```getBindingAdapterPosition()```

Answer (score 0):

By putting the click listener in the RecyclerView.Adapter, you are referencing  and outdated position of the item.

Put the click listener inside the ViewHolder instead. You, can use either layoutPosition or absoluteAdapterPosition
Adapter

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        Log.d(tag, "onBindViewHolder - item at $position is ${item.content}")

        val listener = object : ItemDeleteListener {
            override fun delete(position: Int) {
                items.removeAt(position)
                notifyItemRemoved(position)
            }
        }
        
        holder.bind(item, listener)
    }
```

ViewHolder

```kotlin
fun bind(item: DummyData, listener: ItemDeleteListener) {
        binding.title.text = "${item.content}"

        binding.cta.setOnClickListener {
            listener.delete(layoutPosition)
        }
    }
```

Protip: try not to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` since it's expensive

For more details on how to handle deletion, you can check out this tutorial of mine
(there's sample GitHub repository you can play with too)
https://medium.com/@ericntd/recyclerview-how-to-handle-insertion-and-deletion-334a38104de8